# What is the correct way to return an Interface Type from a Method?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Ok say I have the following simple classes:

```
public interface IResult<T>
{
    T Results { get; set;}
    string Message { get; set;}
}

public class Result<T> : IResult<T>
{
    T Results { get; set;}
    string Message { get; set;}
}

public class Result2<T> : IResult<T>
{
    T Results { get; set;}
    string Message { get; set;}
}
```

Now when I want to call some method to return a IResult, which way is correct?

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool TryDoSomething(out IResult<bool> result)
    {
        // Do stuff
        result.Message = "Out!";
        return true; // for example
    }

    public IResult<bool> DoSomething(IResult<bool> result)
    {
        // Do Stuff
        result.Message = "Sent in!";
        result.Result = true;
        return result;
    }

    public IResult<bool> DoSomething()
    {
        // Do Stuff
        IResult<bool> result = new Result<bool>();
        result.Message = "I'm a Result!";
        result.Result = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now say I actually want a Result2, is it better to create it and send it in as the parameter (methods #1 or #2) or create a new Result but recast it as IResult and then to Result2 as in method #3?

```
public class GetResults
{
    public void GetResults()
    {
        Result2<bool> results = new Result2<bool>();
        if (TryDoSomething(out results))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(results.Message);
        }
        results = DoSomething(results);
        if (results.Result) Debug.WriteLine(results.Message);
        results = DoSomething();
        if (results.Result) Debug.WriteLine(results.Message);
    }
}
```

So is it better to create my interface implementation in the Method or send it in as a parameter?

Comment: You don't need `out` parameters for reference types by the way, those work a little differently from just passing them normally.

Comment: The `Result` and `Result2` must declare the properties they implement from the interface as `public`. Also, the `TestClass.TryDoSomething` has to assign the `result` before using it (because it is declared as "out").

Comment: @BoltClock: You *do* need `out` parameters if the point is for the value to be created by the method which is called. (In this case, `TryDoSomething` wouldn't compile in the first place...)

Comment: If you _require_ a specific concrete type, then coding against interfaces is only going to lead to ugly code with lots of casts so don't do it.  It likely means you're method is dealing with a little Feature Envy _if_ the generalization truly fits to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use `out` parameters as a last resort - unless you *really* want to effectively return two values from the same method, and you've got a good reason not to encapsulate them together (or use `Tuple`), I definitely wouldn't suggest the first approach. (What's the `bool` meant to be for?)

If the *aim* is to manipulate an existing object, then the second method is appropriate - but if the aim is to *create* a result (which is more common, IMO) then the third approach is the most appropriate one.

It's hard to give concrete advice when we've got so little to go on, but personally I favour immutable types where practical, which rules out the second method anyway.

In terms of your question about "I actually want a `Result2`" - *what* wants a `Result2`? The calling code, or the method returning the result? Usually if you're creating a *result* then it's more appropriate for the "creating" code to know which implementation it wants to use.

Comment: I was trying to keep the example as simple as possible so that is why its so basic. For the "I actually want a `Result2<T>`", what I mean is if I use method #3, it always creates a `Result<T>` which is returned as a `IResult<T>` and then cast to `Result2<T>`, is that overhead bad? Or is that ok? Should I do that or create my `Result2<T>` and send it in via method #2? The `bool` was just used as a simple example to be able to check if the methods were successful or not, it could be a `string` or some other type of object as needed, the idea was to not have to have multiple `Result` classes

Comment: @John: If you call a method which is declared to return just an interface, you shouldn't be depending on which implementation is used. Checking whether a method was successful or not is rarely something you should be doing explicitly - failure is idiomatically represented by exceptions. This is exactly the problem with not providing a *concrete* example...

Comment: Yeah I wasn't depending on a certain return type, just trying to show a "its creating this concrete type, but then changing it". I've always done it this way and was just questioning myself as to see if that was the good way, or if I should be creating the concrete type first instead of in my method. Thank you very much for your answers, I've read a lot of your responses on here so am honored you replied to my question :). My `IResult<T>` was created as a replacement for a Tuple so I don't have to deal with random tuple objects all over the place.

Comment: @John regarding your comment "if I use method #3, it always creates a `Result<T>` which is returned as a `IResult<T>` and then cast to `Result2<T>`".  You can't do that.  The cast would fail.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I meant in the sense of method #3 creates the `Result<bool>` and returns it as a `IResult<bool>` and its assigned to a `Result2<bool>`.

Comment: @John but you can't do that either.  Consider: `string` and `int` both implement `IComparable`, but you can't assign a `string` value to an `int` variable.  Similarly, `Result<bool>` and `Result2<bool>` both derive from `IResult<bool>`, but neither derives from the other.  The method returns a reference of type `IResult<bool>` that points to an object of type `Result<bool>`.  Any attempt to assign that value to a reference of `Result2<bool>` will fail.  Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from your comment to Jon's answer, the caller can specify what type is desired without creating the object, assuming the class has a public parameterless constructor:

```
public TResult DoSomething<TResult, U>() where TResult : IResult<U>, new()
{
    // Do Stuff     
    TResult result = new TResult();     
    result.Message = "I'm a Result!";     
    result.Result = true;     
    return result;     
}
```

usage:

```
Result<bool> result1 = DoSomething<Result<bool>, bool>();
Result2<bool> result2 = DoSomething<Result2<bool>, bool>();
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you :), where could I find some documentation on this?

Comment: @John http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(v=vs.100).aspx is the documentation for the `new()` constraint.